# Запустить YouTube видео по клику на ссылку?

Tags: html, javascript

Как при клике на ссылку запустить YouTube видео?

Есть ссылка

```
<a href="">Смотреть видео</a>
```

При клике на нее нужно, чтобы видео начало воспроизводиться...

Код видео

```
<iframe width="660" height="353" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BSU8MvdEwaY?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Думаю, чуть больше информации для размышления над ответом не повредит, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BSU8MvdEwaY?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1">Click</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не так давно мне повстречался отличный плагин, [YouTubePopUp](http://wp-time.com/youtube-popup-jquery-plugin/).

Для себя лично я дорабатывал JS, вдруг пригодится:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var link = $("#rotation_banners a").attr('href');
    if (typeof link !== 'undefined' && link.match(/(youtube.com)/)){
        $("#rotation_banners a").YouTubePopUp();
    }
    if ($(".youtube").length > 0) {
        $(".youtube").YouTubePopUp();
    }
});

/*
    Name: YouTubePopUp
    Description: jQuery plugin to display YouTube or Vimeo video in PopUp, responsive and retina, easy to use.
    Version: 1.0.1
    Plugin URL: http://wp-time.com/youtube-popup-jquery-plugin/
    Written By: Qassim Hassan
    Updated By: Makarenko Ivan
    Twitter: @QQQHZ
    Websites: wp-time.com | qass.im | wp-plugins.in
    Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
        http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
        http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
    Copyright (c) 2016 - Qassim Hassan

    Updated: 2016.06.25
    Updated by: Ivan Makarenko
    Description: Add supporting of other links to youtube video, and more settings
    See: more settings https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=ru
*/
var auto_close = true;
var ik_player;
//this function is called by the API
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(playerid) {
    playerid = 'youtube-iframe';
    ik_player = new YT.Player(playerid, {
        events: {
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
        }
    });
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if(event.data == '0' && auto_close) {
        // destroy pop-up
        $('.YouTubePopUp-Wrap').addClass('YouTubePopUp-Hide').delay(515).queue(function() { $(this).remove(); });
    }
}

(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.YouTubePopUp = function(options) {
        // include YouTubeAPI
        if ($("script[src^='//www.youtube.com/player_api']").length === 0) {
            var s = document.createElement("script");
            s.src = "//www.youtube.com/player_api";
            $("head").append(s);
        }

        // turn off auto close on complete
        // and remove from options because not iframe option
        if (options !== undefined && options.autoclose !== undefined) {
            if (options.autoclose === 0) {
                auto_close = false;
            }
            delete options.autoclose;
        }
        var YouTubePopUpOptions = $.extend({
                autoplay: 1,
                rel: 0,         // show relevant video after play? (1|0) if 0 auto close after end of playing
                enablejsapi: 1, // access to use YouTube JS API (1|0)
                showinfo: 0,    // show title and author info (1|0)
                playerapiid: 'youtube-iframe',
                v: 3,
        }, options );

        $(this).on('click', function (e) {

            // get youtube link from data or from href
            var youtubeLink = $(this).data('youtube-link');
            if (typeof youtubeLink == 'undefined') {
                youtubeLink = $(this).attr('href');
            }

            // default aspect ratio is 4 by 3 but if set data full-wide is true then 16 by 9
            var aspectRatio = $(this).data('aspect-ratio');
            if(aspectRatio == '4by3') {
                aspectRatio = 'embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3';
            } else {
                aspectRatio = 'embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9';
            }

            var split_c, split_n;
            if( youtubeLink.match(/(youtube.com)/) ){
                split_c = 'v=';
                split_n = 1;
            }

            if( youtubeLink.match(/(youtube.com\/embed\/)/) ){
                split_c = 'embed/';
                split_n = 1;
            }

            if( youtubeLink.match(/(youtube.com\/v\/)/) ){
                split_c = 'youtube.com/v/';
                split_n = 1;
            }

            if( youtubeLink.match(/(youtu.be)/) || youtubeLink.match(/(vimeo.com\/)+[0-9]/) ){
                split_c = '/';
                split_n = 3;
            }

            if( youtubeLink.match(/(vimeo.com\/)+[a-zA-Z]/) ){
                split_c = '/';
                split_n = 5;
            }

            var getYouTubeVideoID = youtubeLink.split(split_c)[split_n];

            var cleanVideoID = getYouTubeVideoID.replace(/(&)+(.*)/, '');

            var videoEmbedLink = '', count = 0, key;
            if( youtubeLink.match(/(youtu.be)/) || youtubeLink.match(/(youtube.com)/) ){
                videoEmbedLink = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+cleanVideoID+'';
                // add settings
                count = 0;
                for(key in YouTubePopUpOptions) {
                    if (count < 1) {
                        videoEmbedLink += '?';
                    } else {
                        videoEmbedLink += '&';
                    }
                    videoEmbedLink += key+'='+YouTubePopUpOptions[key]+'';
                    count++;
                }
            }

            if( youtubeLink.match(/(vimeo.com\/)+[0-9]/) || youtubeLink.match(/(vimeo.com\/)+[a-zA-Z]/) ){
                videoEmbedLink = 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/'+cleanVideoID+'';
                // add settings
                count = 0;
                for(key in YouTubePopUpOptions) {
                    if (count < 1) {
                        videoEmbedLink += '?';
                    } else {
                        videoEmbedLink += '&';
                    }
                    videoEmbedLink += key+'='+YouTubePopUpOptions[key]+'';
                    count++;
                }
            }

            // append pop-up
            $('body').append('<div class="YouTubePopUp-Wrap"><div class="YouTubePopUp-Content"><div class="'+aspectRatio+'"><span class="YouTubePopUp-Close"></span><iframe id="youtube-iframe" src="'+videoEmbedLink+'" allowfullscreen></iframe></div></div></div>');

            $('.YouTubePopUp-Wrap, .YouTubePopUp-Close').click(function(){
                $('.YouTubePopUp-Wrap').addClass('YouTubePopUp-Hide').delay(515).queue(function() { $(this).remove(); });
            });

            onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();
            e.preventDefault();

        });

        $(document).keyup(function(e) {

            if ( e.keyCode == 27 ){
                $('.YouTubePopUp-Wrap, .YouTubePopUp-Close').click();
            }

        });
    };

}( jQuery ));
```